# Who ate my comment?

Tags: support, comments

In this question:

[The most difficult countries to travel in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/the-most-difficult-countries-to-travel-in/5812#5812)

I wrote a rather lengthy comment in reply to mouviciel explaining why pilgrimage visas aren't a realistic option, and hippietrail responded to my comment -- but the actual comment is gone. Who ate it, why and is there any logging or is it just down the memory hole?

Comment: Did you comment on the question or on an answer to the question? Normally there's a sign of it somewhere for us to find..

Comment: There's an answer you wrote down the bottom - you don't mean that do you? It's still [there](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5812/101)...

Comment: No, I meant my own comment in response to mouviciel's comment, outlining why pilgrimage visas don't work for tourism: 1) only for Muslims, 2) strict quotas, and 3) limit you to Medda, Medina and Jeddah.

Comment: ah found it. It was flagged for stuff about ... certain body parts being chopped off being part of the Muslim religion.  I can't undelete it (no option) but come into the [chat] and I can paste it for you to edit and repost if you like.

Comment: I've pasted it there and discussed.

Comment: Um, circumcision **is** a part of the Muslim religion, so shame on you for knee-jerk censorship without the common courtesy of even notifying me.

Answer (score 2):

> Who ate it

*This comment was deleted by the system, because several ordinary users flagged it as offensive. Mods can always undelete comments that any other mods deleted. But comments deleted by ordinary users can't be undeleted by anyone. (Though mods can view such comments.)*

quoted from a Comment by @Michael Hampton (thank you!) to correct my error.

> why

being about religion was deemed potentially contentious.

> is there any logging

Yes, though deleted Comments are not 'recoverable' by users other than mods.

> or is it just down the memory hole

No, it has been recovered and (with some modification) incorporated into an A.

Comment: It wasn't a mod. This comment was deleted by the system, because several ordinary users flagged it as offensive. Mods can always undelete comments that any other mods deleted. But comments deleted by ordinary users can't be undeleted by anyone. (Though mods can _view_ such comments.)